# Is there a way to make the value_count() function more sensitive when counting occurences of textual data in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am currently preprocessing a dataset for an unsupervised machine learning algorithm, when trying to use the value_count() function to group and count occurrences of textual data, it does not seem to be as sensitive. For example, I have a column with range values as inputs such as 1 - 5, 5 - 10, 50 - 100 and so on, however in the same column I have data like 20-Jun and so on. While using the value_count function, it does not account for inputs like 20 - Jun at all just other range of values

```
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('mental-heath-in-tech-2016_20161114.csv')

ndata = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

#for loop to visualize data which has 63 columns
for i in range(63):
    colname = ndata.columns[i] #get names of ith column
    values = ndata[colname].value_counts(dropna=False)  #group and count amount of value occurences
    print(f'Column {i}: \n', values)   #print grouped info
    total = sum(values)  #get total of valid input in ith feature
    Miss = 1433 - total  #amount of null input in ith feature
    null = ndata[colname].isna().sum()
    print('Sum: ', total)  #print total valid input
    print('Missing: ', Miss)   #print amount of missing inputs
    print('Null: ', null)
    print()  #new lines
```

Comment: You could do something like removing spaces? This may not work given the nature of you data, but might give you some ideas.`df[col] = df[col].str.replace('  ','')`

Comment: @BrendanA, Tried it, same thing. Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the `values = ...` line to `values = ndata[colname].str.replace('  ','').str.lower().value_counts(dropna=False)`

Comment: I did and finally able to remove the spaces but still is not sensitive enough. Thanks